# Twisted Jacquet Module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

All the groups considered will be Hausdorff, totally disconnected and locally compact groups. And all representations will be smooth representations over the complex numbers.

Let $G$ be a group and $(V,\pi)$ an irreducible representations. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\lambda$ be a linear character of $N$. So we can consider the twisted Jacquet module $V_\lambda =V/V(\lambda)$, where:

$$V(\lambda)=\langle\pi(n)v-\lambda(n)v\;|\;v\in V,\;n\in N\rangle_{\mathbb C}.$$

My question is: $V_\lambda$ is irreducible as a $Z_G(\lambda)$-module? If not when is it?

Comment: No to the first question, in general, and … it's not quite clear what kind of answer you'd like for the second question.

Comment: I'm interested in the case that $G=H\rtimes A$ with A an abelian group acting on $H$, and $H$ a group that is union of its compacts.

I'm looking more at why it may fail to be irreducible.

Comment: And $N$ is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Sorry, that's two stupid comments in a row from me; I gave an example where $V(\lambda)$ was reducible, not where $V_\lambda$ was reducible.  I delete them both.  If you have additional conditions in mind on $G$ or $N$, it's probably a good idea to edit them into the question.

Comment: (I originally thought that you were asking in the 'usual' situation where $G$ is (the group of $k$-points of) a reductive group and $N$ is the unipotent radical of a parabolic subgroup $P = M N$, and we consider your $V_\lambda$ as a representation of $\mathrm C_M(\lambda)$; there the possible failure of irreducibility is obvious.  This question is more interesting ….)

Comment: I'm more interested in "smaller" case, for example, where $G=TU$ , with $T$ a torus, and $U$ an unipotent group. Or in another way, instead of starting with a irreducible representation of a reductive group, I start with a irreducible representation of the borel subgroup of a reductive group.